# Expanding short name from argument

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I know that by using `%~s1` I can expand first argument to short path ([ref](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx))

Now I have this strange issue that file extension is added to this shortened path for some reason. For example, consider this simple batch file, called `test.cmd`:

```
@echo %1
@echo %~s1
```

If I pass this argument:

```
C:\>test.cmd "C:\Documents and Settings\zzz\My Documents\My Music\Library\I AWAKE\[2008] The Core\I Awake - The Cor.m4a"
"C:\Documents and Settings\zzz\My Documents\My Music\Library\I AWAKE\[2008] The Core\I Awake - The Cor.m4a"
C:\DOCUME~1\zzz\MYDOCU~1\MYMUSI~1\Library\IAWAKE~1\_2008_~1\I Awake - The Cor.m4am4a
```

you can see that 'm4a' is added to returned shortened path.

Does someone know why is this happening?

---

**Update**

If anyone is willing here is how it can be reproduced (I used same folder names as I don't know it's related to some of the characters used):

```
C:\Temp>md "My Documents\Library\I AWAKE\[2008] The Core\"
C:\Temp>echo test > "My Documents\Library\I AWAKE\[2008] The Core\I Awake - The Core.dat"
C:\Temp>test.cmd "c:\Temp\My Documents\Library\I AWAKE\[2008] The Core\I Awake - The Core.dat"
```

[image: img]

Note that filename isn't shortened, although it exists. Here is what happens if filename doesn't need to be shortened:

[image: img]

It has something to do with `I AWAKE` folder name. If I change other folder names I get this wrong result, but if I change `I AWAKE` to other name (that doesn't start with `I ...`) I get correct result

Comment: I tried it and I do not get the extra ext behavior.  You should specify which version of windows OS you are running on.  Also it appears to only shorten the path if the path actually exists... so for me it shortened the C:\DOCUME~1\  but not the "my documents" or after... .

Comment: Doesn't go wrong here either (Win 7)  `C:\>test2.cmd  "C:\Documents and Settings\zzz\My Documents\My Music\Library\I AW
AKE\[2008] The Core\I Awake - The Cor.m4a"
"C:\Documents and Settings\zzz\My Documents\My Music\Library\I AWAKE\[2008] The
Core\I Awake - The Cor.m4a"
C:\DOCUME~1\zzz\My Documents\My Music\Library\I AWAKE\[2008] The Core\I Awake -
The Cor.m4a`

Comment: confirmed.  %~s1 will only shorten it if that part of the path actually exists.

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce this here, no extra extension is added.

Comment: 2nd the Windows 7 doesn't have this problem

Comment: Thanks guys, you are right - path needs to exist so that shortening could actually work. I'm on XP and I attached CLI screenshot.

Comment: Should also point out that **.BAT** is the default extension for batch files. Sure, **.CMD** is legal, but there are minor differences in the way a `.CMD` works. I'm afraid I can't recall quite what they are at present since `.CMD` is used very rarely and I don't encounter them often enough. Best to stick with `.BAT` IMHO.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I get same results with .bat extension unfortunately.

Comment: Please show the output from `type test.cmd`.

Comment: @mfm4aa: please see updated question. I added additional screenshot

Comment: Sorry again: have the same XP version here and NOT this effect.

Comment: Neee: Now confirm! `test.cmd "My Documents\Library\I AWAKE\[2008] The Core\I Awake - The Core.dat"` (without c:\temp\) i got the same effect now! Have to look into this ...

Comment: Great :D I can't make sense still...

Comment: OK, but what's the pattern? What triggers it? When should I care?...

Answer (score 1):

After some recherche I found only one website concerning this issue: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/long-filename-short-filename-conversion-incorrect-t3693699.html. The error occurs in paths with two 'long names' inside, the character length also plays a role:

```
C:>md "12345 6789\t st"

C:>echo test> "12345 6789\t st\test.dat"

C:>for /r "12345 6789" %i in (*.*) do @echo %~si
C:\123456~1\TST~1\test.datt
```

Here occurs an additional `t`. If the first path name becomes longer, the extension also becomes longer and longer:

```
 C:>for /r "12345     6789" %i in (*.*) do @echo %~si
 C:\123456~1\TST~1\test.datt.dat
```

The `dir /x` command isn't affected.

Comment: It doesn't look that the problem is with "paths with two 'long names' inside", as for rest such paths I have no issue. Question is still how can we determine when this command will fail, and then use some workaround. Or of course, avoid using it at all.

Comment: I think that there is no safety. This function can always fail. In a for loop you can safe use: `for /f "tokens=4" %i in ('dir "*.*" /s /a-d /x^|findstr [0-9]:') do @echo %~i`.